# Java cipher update method

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to learn encoding in Java and stuck with Cipher.update() method. Does it have some maximum length of data it can update?
Here is an example of what I'm speaking (I put "String s" value just to speed up process, this value goes through encryption and decryption process):

```
public class AES {
    public static String s = "long string";

    public byte [] encryptAES(byte[] data, byte[] keyPass) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        SecretKeySpec AESkeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, "AES");
        ciph.init(ENCRYPT_MODE,AESkeySpec);

        ciph.update(s.getBytes());
        byte[] encryptedData = ciph.doFinal();

        return encryptedData;
    }
}
```

Output after decryption: `long string`

If I change value

```
public static String s = "long long long long long long long long long long long string";
```

output after decoding will be: `g long string`

And if after I take out `.update()` method and perform encryption like

```
Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

SecretKeySpec AESkeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, "AES");
ciph.init(ENCRYPT_MODE,AESkeySpec);
//ciph.update(s.getBytes());

byte[] encryptedData = ciph.doFinal(s.getBytes());
return encryptedData;
```

I will get expected output like: `long long long long long long long long long long long string`

Why does it happen like that?

Comment: `"AES"` for `Cipher` will use the provider's default. For the SUN provider, that would be `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`. You should use at least `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` (requires a random IV) or `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"` (requires a unique IV). Always specify the mode of operation and padding explicitly. And never use `getBytes()` without specifying a character encoding.

Comment: I know that, ty. This example above was just for learning of methods, not the part of some project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `update` method returns encrypted block. But as I see you take the ciphertext only from `doFinal`. You supposed to use all blocks from `update` and from the `doFinal` for completed encrypted stream of blocks.

Note: you are using ECB mode, it means each block encrypted independently, it is less secure and should be used only if you know what are you doing. That's why you are able to decrypt the last block (16 bytes for AES) and see truncated plaintext. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Answer (score 3):

For ECB and CBC [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation), each block (128 bits or 16 bytes for AES) of plaintext or will be encrypted once it is available. Furthermore, your example uses [PKCS#7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) (or, in Java, `"PKCS5Padding"`) to make sure that the last plaintext is padded to a full block. Otherwise you would not be able to encrypt it.

When you encrypt it is obviously not a good idea to buffer all the resulting ciphertext. So `update` will simply return all blocks it *can* encrypt. Therefore you will always get a multiple of the blocksize back. That means that it *may* keep part of a block in an internal buffer. Of course, once you add enough bytes for a full block it will encrypt and return the data. All this means that the update **may return up to `blocksize - 1` bytes more or less than the input**. For smaller input it may not return anything at all - everything is buffered until the block is full.

Now PKCS#7 padding is *always* applied, adding 1 to blocksize bytes. Obviously the cipher must know if more bytes are to be expected, or if the end of the plaintext is reached, before it applies the padding. So `doFinal` will return at least one block, even if no data is presented to it. If the previous updates did not return any data, then the `doFinal()` method will return the entire ciphertext.

More or less the same reasoning can be performed for decryption. Also note the [`getOutputSize(int inputLength)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getOutputSize(int)) and the [`getBlockSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getBlockSize()) methods of [`Cipher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). If you want to receive all the data back at once, you can use a stream cipher mode of operation, such as `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"`, which has a block size of 1 byte.

---

Although this should explain the actual issue, the question you asked was "Does it have some maximum length of data it can update?". The answer is that the update is only limited by the amount of memory available in the JVM and the size of byte arrays in Java.

Comment: Ty, that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`cipher.update()` returns the ciphertext produced for that plaintext.

If you ignore that ciphertext, you won't be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Didn't quite understand, how am I ignoring it? I'm just changing the value of String s, and getting different output depending on length of string.

Comment: @Mikekekeke: You're ignoring the bytes returned by `update()`.

Comment: But why I'm not loosing this bytes if String s = "long string"? (Sry if my questions are too stupid :) )

Comment: @Mikekekeke: Because that's part of the final block returned by `doFinal()`.

Comment: It doesn't precisely produce the ciphertext for that plaintext, so this answer is plain wrong (for ECB and CBC mode of operation anyway).